# Unable to check the value of a variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, boolean

I need to check a variable `vi_theIndex` for its value. At the given moment it has a value of 65.

I want to check if `vi_theIndex` is bigger or equal to zero AND smaller than 32.
Right now I do it like this:

```
long long vi_theIndex = 65;
if ((vi_theIndex >= 0) && (vi_theIndex < 32) )
 {
   //Case true
 }
else
{
   //Case false
}
```

I realized that the results are wrong for 65. The second case should come up but the first case becomes true. Why is this?

I tried this:

```
long long vi_theIndex = 65;

bool limitFlag1, limitFlag2;

limitFlag1 = (vi_theIndex <= 0);
limitFlag2 = (vi_theIndex = 65);
```

`limitFlag2` becomes true and `limitFlag1` becomes undefined, the debugger doesn´t even stop there on my breakpoint. It looks like C doesn´t understand the '<', '<=' or '>' signs. This also happens when I use the '<' or '>' sign alone like here:

```
limitFlag1 = (vi_theIndex < 0);
```

`limitFlag1` is not defined.

Can somebody please shed some light on this?

Comment: I think it should be limitFlag2 = (vi_theIndex == 65);

Comment: And why are you using a long long? considering the range your checking and the possible maximum of vi_theIndex, you should change what the type you are storing the index in to a smaller type. Also due to cache misses you should change it so you current false statement becomes the true statement because for each instance of 33 or66 up to MAX long long you will receive a cache miss.....and thats a lot of cache misses

Comment: Cache miss?  Do you mean branch mispredict?  I expect the compiler would take care of it anyway.

Comment: No optimizations at all.

the three lines 
    bool limitFlag1, limitFlag2;
    limitFlag1 = (vi_theIndex <= 0);
    limitFlag2 = (vi_theIndex = 65);

I put in after I realized that the comparison failed to check what´s wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not be showing your real code for your first example - as you say, "case false" should be executed.

Your second example has a problem - you have `vi_theIndex = 65`, rather than `vi_theIndex == 65`, which you probably meant.  The statement as you have it is always true.  `limitFlag1` will be `0` - I'm not sure what you mean by it "becomes undefined" - are you not showing your real code here, too?

Comment: Yes, of course, vi_theIndex == ws meant.
'becomes undefined' means that normally the variables are visible below in the debugger with its values. limitFlag1 just doesn´t show in the debugger.

Comment: Do you have a bunch of optimizations turned on?  Sometimes variables that have been optimized to exist only in registers (rather than in memory) don't work very well in debuggers.